# Only Install migration is applying on plugin install

Tags: craft3, migration

I have a custom plugin which is added via path repository on local.
I have some migrations in the `src` folder.

My problem is if I uninstall the plugin and install it again, I can see all of the migrations in the migration table, but only Install migration is applied.

If I change the version and schema version of the plugin and remove and require the plugin again, I get update plugin notification on the dashboard and all of the migrations are applied correctly.

also if i create and apply these migrations via command i can see change in databases.

i don't why migrations aren't applied on plugin install -except Install migration-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it's working as expected.

When you add a new migration for your plugin, you're expected to update your plugin's Install.php migration with the new schema changes as well.

You can see the relevant code here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/base/Plugin.php#L149-L161

Comment: thanks. so when we change database schema, we have to create a separate migration for current installations and update install.php for new installations? what is the point of this special install.php migration anyway?